# Is it possible to center a form while maintaining separation of content and presentation?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT 5/21/13 13:40 EST**: Added `inline-block` styling.

Considering the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            form { display: inline-block; }
        </style>
        <title>Log in </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way in CSS to center the form without

- Adding extra divs à la the bootstrap grid
- Guessing what the width of the form will be in percentage or px
- Center-aligning the text inside the form

Basically, I want the block that contains the form to have its width determined automatically by its contents, then have the center of that block lined up with the center of the page.

Comment: All done and said before: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: You need to be more specific as regards the div's that surround the form. A form based on your code will occupy 100% width of the screen DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/M42ug/ so in theory it is centered.

Comment: @Vector Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm making the form inline-block. Will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `display: table`, not `display: inline-block`.  Both display types have that *shrink to fit* behavior you're looking for, but `table` allows you to use margins for the purpose of centering.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/slpqdfct

```
form {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `display: table` will not work in IE 7.  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html