# How to get minimal width behavior (such as when floating or pos: abs) without using a float or pos: abs

Tags: css, css-float, width

Let's say I have a block element, such as an h2:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
```

And I give it a background color.  The background will span the entire width of the wrapper (as it should).

If I float it, or `position: absolute`, it will 'shrink wrap' the words. However, both of these methods take the element out of the 'flow' and prevent it from pushing the rest of the content down the page.

I'd like to avoid having to add a clear underneath the title every time.  Is there a better solution?  I thought the `overflow` property could do it, but I'm not figuring it out.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QxRRh/

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? I don't understand what you mean by "minimal width behaviour".

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Make the `h2` shrink to fit its contents by width without any of the side effects associated with floating or absposing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center a form while maintaining separation of content and presentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675524/is-it-possible-to-center-a-form-while-maintaining-separation-of-content-and-pres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one (very simple) way ...

```
h2 {
    display: table;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwB57/1/)

Comment: Why use this (which won't work in older IE's for example) instead of `display: inline`?

Comment: Because using `inline` or `inline-block` would make the element `inline` or `inline-block` (obviously). Not what the OP wants

Comment: doh! display: inline, or inline-block.  why don't you add an answer - this is a question and answer site, not a question and comment site :O

Comment: well - as long as the NEXT element is block, inline will work

Comment: @Mike Lewis: `display: table` works with IE8+ and everything else, which really isn't much better or worse than `display: inline-block`. Semantics don't really matter when you're talking about CSS, unless you're one of those OOCSS hipsters.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the header text in a `<span>` and apply the background color to that span.

HTML:

`<h2><span class="blue">Title</span></h2>`

CSS:

`.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}`

Comment: I changed the wording, there is more than one way to achieve this.

Comment: This would be similar to adding a clear underneath - I was trying to avoid extra markup

Comment: This way does not change how the header is displayed and gives the result you want.